# ST_Expand return different results depending on meters

Tags: postgis

I am very confused by getting different results from st_expand (srid 4326).
I want to do a search within a bounding box, therefore I pass a point and I'd like to provide distance in meters in order to see if I will get a macht.

So this  query is returning a result:

`select "geo_name_cities".* FROM "geo_name_cities" WHERE (name like '%Ischgl%' AND      ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (10.3298112 46.9809071)', 4326),5000) && lonlat)`

my assumption here. Make a bounding box of 5000 meters around the point.

Now I increase to 6000m

```
select "geo_name_cities".* FROM "geo_name_cities" WHERE (name like '%Ischgl%' AND ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (10.3298112 46.9809071)', 4326),6000) && lonlat)
```

No result. Ok, I might assume that the place is not within this box, fine.
BUT when I use 60000m I get a  result again ?????

`select "geo_name_cities".* FROM "geo_name_cities" WHERE (name like '%Ischgl%' AND    ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (10.3298112 46.9809071)', 4326),60000) && lonlat)`

So I increased the distance steadily but the results are different, how does this come?

Comment: Are you *sure* the unit is meters?  It's possible you're seeing a difference between 5000 degrees and 6000 degrees.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching planet\_osm\_point by longitude and latitude](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93936/searching-planet-osm-point-by-longitude-and-latitude) or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/how-do-i-use-st-dwithin-with-meters?rq=1

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63981/st-dwithin-uses-geometry-or-geography-type, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70781/attempting-to-use-st-dwithin-to-locate-objects-within-a-given-distance-of-meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is covered by brad and vince: you're mixing up units.

A second issue: consider using [`ST_DWithin()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead of a [`ST_Expand()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html) and [`&&`](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) combination. There's a lot of Q&As using ST_DWithin() around. E.g., [Searching planet_osm_point by longitude and latitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93936/searching-planet-osm-point-by-longitude-and-latitude/93957#93957)

Comment: ST_DWithin()  is working great (much faster). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As Vince pointed out, [ST_Expand](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Expand.html)() is working in units of the spatial reference system you are using, which for EPSG:4326 is degrees. Some functions will have wrap-around effects and other aliasing artifacts when you ask for extreme numbers (like 5000 degrees).

Try projecting into a local coordinate system using metres. I'd use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to convert from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:32633 (UTM Zone 33N), do the expand there, and transform back. That may lose some of the benefits of ST_Expand that you were hoping to achieve, so perhaps ST_Buffer might be more suitable. Depends on your specific situation.

Comment: is it not possible to convert degrees into meters. so i could keep on using my query but using a transformed meter value?

Comment: Its possible, but non-trivial for longitude (X) values because of convergence. That is, 1 degree of longitude a the equator is many more metres than 1 degree of longitude near the poles.